# how to change the class variable depending on the variable from the constructor?

Tags: python

I want to change the `class variable` depending on the `variable` from the `constructor`.

In the case of the code below, I expect the console to show `Yes` but the result is `No`.

How could I change the variable by the `constructor`?

here is the code:

```
class MyClass:
    is_check = False

    def __init__(self, is_check):
        self.is_check = is_check

    if is_check:
        val = 'Yes'
    else:
        val = 'No'


print(MyClass(True).val)
```

---

Python 3.8

Comment: There is an indentation issue here... Or if you really intend that `if..else` to be there, then it'll execute as part of the class definition, before any instance is created.

Comment: Note, `self.is_check = is_check` creates an instance variable. If you want to modify the actually class variable then use `MyClass.is_check = is_check` or maybe `type(self).is_check = is_check` (not exactly equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class definition should look like this -
There is an indentation issue as pointed out by @trincot
The variable `var` should be a object variable, as in make it `self.var`

The variable declaration has to be className.variable for it to not create an instance variable , and have only one variable for all objects of the class to use as in class variable. Pointed out by @juanpa.arrivillaga

```
class MyClass:
    is_check = False

    def __init__(self, is_check):
        MyClass.is_check = is_check
        

        if is_check:
            self.val = 'Yes'
        else:
            self.val = 'No'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- The `if..else` block executes before any instance is created, so it could not possibly reflect a change to `is_check`
- When *writing* to a class attribute, you should not use `self.is_check` as assigning to that will create an instance attribute that just happens to have the same name.

For `val` you could create a property, so that it will always reflect the *current* value of the class attribute. In this case you can use `self.is_check`, but only if you don't make the mistake mentioned in the previous point

So:

```
class MyClass:
    is_check = False

    def __init__(self, is_check):
        MyClass.is_check = is_check

    @property
    def val(self):
        return 'Yes' if self.is_check else 'No'


print(MyClass(True).val)
```